# Oracle invalid number error executing java batch

Tags: java, oracle, sh

I'm having troubles with executing a java batch from an sh script. Essentially, I'm using a sh script which pass two arguments (dates) to the runnable jar file in order to update the DB.

The error I'm getting is "ORA-01722: invalid number.

I know the script and the parameters I'm passing to the jar are good because I'm running the command from my pc and it works. The problem is when running the sh from the server directly. The sql that the jar executes also is ok since it works directly from my DB console and from the jar from my pc.

The command I'm using is: java -jar JavaFile.jar 20170101 20170107.

Any idea why this could be happening?

Edit 1: the sh contains exactly that java sentence and the jar works, the problem must be something related to oracle configuration or some kind of bug.

I can't share much code since it's confidencial.

Comment: http://www.dba-oracle.com/sf_ora_01722_invalid_number.htm it can be helpful for you.

Comment: It's impossible to answer a question like this without more context. Please share your code.

Comment: Oracle depends on session settings for the default format for dates and numbers. Probably, your PC has other settings than the server. Maybe you need to set those settings to well-defined values, as in `alter session set nls_numeric_characters='.,';`

Comment: @Mureinik I'm not sharing actual code since it's confidencial. I'm sorry for asking the much.

Comment: @Erich I tried your approach and it worked. I'm now altering the session (into the exact same values my sqlDeveloper's connection has) and everything went just perfect. Feel free to answer the question so I can take it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle depends on session settings for the default format for dates and numbers. Probably, your PC has other settings than the server. Maybe you need to set those settings to well-defined values, as in `alter session set nls_numeric_characters='.,';`